# Regex - Capitalizing the first letter after xml tags

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++

I'm trying to use Notepad++ regex feature to change all tags first letter to capital in a xml file. Something like this:

```
<name> -> <Name>
<productNumber> -> <ProductNumber>
```

and

```
</name> -> </Name>
</productNumber> -> </ProductNumber>
```

Ive followed some other close post here where the user wanted to change the value inside a tag. Something like this:

```
<p>asd</p> -> <p>Asd</p>
```

The solution for this was:

Find: `(?<=<p>)(.)`

Replace: `\U\1`

But changing `<p>` to `<` is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

*Find what*: `(</?)(\pL)`
*Replace with*: `$1\u$2`

where `(</?)` captures `<` and an optional `/` into Group 1 and a letter into Group 2, and only Group 2 contents are turned to upper case.

The `\u` turns the next character, here, it is the matched letter, to uppercase.

[image]

Comment: Hi! When i press the replace button it's not replacing to upper case for some reason.
Edit: wait it seems using replace all is working. Let me get back to you.

Comment: Did you check *Regular expression* option? Also, try with `</?\K[a-z]` regex, it should also work the same. What is your input?'

Comment: Yes it only works when i choose replace all. Not if i replace one by one.

Comment: Yes, that is a known issue.

Comment: Well now i feel stupid lol. Ok ill mark it as the correct answer.
Thanks.

Comment: I found another way to make `Replace` work: `(</?)([a-z])` -> `$1\u$2`

Comment: Using the `\p` script was neat

Comment: Is it possible to add to this filter the option to change the tag <vip> to <VIP> ? This is the only tag where i need all capital letters.

Comment: Use `(</?)(vip>|\pL)` and replace with `$1\U$2`